# return static character array by using reference

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, reference

Now I want to write a new version of the following code:

```
const char * f() {
     return "Hello";
} 
const char *pf = f();
```

I wonder how to use `reference` instead of `pointer`.

I have one idea by using `string`.

Is there a more straight way to solve this?

UPDATE:

I read the answer and comments carefully. I got **another idea** *is to treat the return value as a **const char array**. But this solution seems too complicated and not so clear as a pointer.*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You mean you want to use string instead of char * and return it's address?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  just want to make a clear map between pointer and reference.

Comment: @MaximMakhun I mean use `string` to replace `char *`

Comment: @luoluo: what? why? The pointer and the reference will point at the same address.

Comment: I mean accomplish the same goal(return a static string) by using reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the syntax then the definition will look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

const char ( & ( f() ) )[6] { return ( "Hello" ); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

Or as @Jarod42 advices you can use a typedef that the fiunction definition woild look simpler

```
#include <iostream>

const char ( & ( f() ) )[6] { return ( "Hello" ); }

typedef const char ( &Array_Ref )[6];
Array_Ref g() { return ( "Hello" ); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
    std::cout << g() << std::endl;

    Array_Ref s = g();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;    
}
```

If you want to use std::string then it would be better to write the function as

```
std::string f() { return ( "Hello" ); }
```

Comment: I would used a `typedef`... The syntax to pass array by reference isn't nice, the syntax to return array is worst...

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree but it is useful to see how it looks at least one time.

Comment: Btw, there is a superfluous parenthesis around `f()`: `const char (&f())[6]` is enough.

Comment: @Jarod42  Yes, but I thought it will make the definition more clear.

Comment: But how can this assign to some variable as the `pointer` did?

Comment: @@luoluo Arrays has no the assignment operator but you can assign a reference of the same type. For example Array_Ref s = g(); I have uodated my post

Comment: I think it would be a little bit easier to understand if reference wouldn't be a part of typedef. It's a question of taste of course.
typedef const char OurCharArray[6];
OurCharArray& g() { return ( "Hello" ); }

Comment: Sorry, I know this is silly, but i really find it awesome that many of Vlad's typos appear to be phonetically appropriate.

Comment: @Steven Lu And what is the conclusion? :)

Comment: No conclusion. I was simply entertained. Keep doing what you do. :)