# C++ template/macro "function" that finds size of array

Tags: c++

Here's a weird situation.

I found this code. I traced it down in my source code to a commit on March 2011. I have no comment next to it, but I am fairly certain it is an adaptation of something that I saw on this very Q&A site.

```
namespace detail {
       template <typename T, size_t N>
       char (&SIZEOF_ARRAY_REQUIRES_ARRAY(T (&)[N]))[N];
}
#define SIZEOF(x) sizeof(detail::SIZEOF_ARRAY_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARGUMENT(x))
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
int buffer[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("Size of buffer: %u\n", SIZEOF(buffer)); // prints 5 instead of 8 (or 4)
```

I cannot use this template/macro/whatever this is on regular items. So I cannot just be cavalier about it and replace all my `sizeof()` with this. I have to be careful to only use this in the case that I am lazy and want to fetch the size of a buffer I just allocated on the stack. That's like literally the only place this is useful, and indeed the only place I have ever used this, and I only ever used it once.

Neither is it clear, even now, or should I say, especially now, why this works. This is the actual purpose of this question. Why does this thing even work? How does it work? What is this a template **of**? Is it a function? *What is this magic??*

<s>I intend to delete this code now, mainly because of how fundamentally useless it is, but before I do so,</s> I must get to the bottom of why it does what it does.

Comment: It declares a function that returns a reference to an `char` array of a specific dimension. What is particularly interesting to note and occasionally makes people double-take is it is **only** a declaration. no actual *implementation* is required, as all we care about is the return *type*.  The `sizeof` that type is what is ultimately the end-goal.

Comment: See the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Anyway, `std::array` has a `size` member function by the way.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right you are. I figured it out about 3 seconds before you posted your comment. I reckon someone will beat me to writing a proper answer, so I'll just let that happen. It sure is a clever little thing. Yeah I think at the time I was not really into learning the new fancy C++11 stuff. Nowadays we mess around with std::array for this.

Comment: It isn't uncommon either. Many implementations use it for a `countof()` macro like yours. If you have access to Microsoft's library src (any version since at least 2005) you'll see they have employed it for some time now.

Comment: An alternative is a regular `constexpr` function.

Comment: @WhozCraig Are there any more uses for this thing than measuring the size of buffers on the stack? I can't decide if I should keep it around now. Does regular `sizeof(buffer)` simply return the size of the `int*`? That bugs me.

Comment: It obviously also works for any static-linkage native array as well (globals, statics, etc). Its real benefit is utter failure to allow compilation when passed pointer-types. The MS blog that discusses it [can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx). circa 2004, so I was off by at least a year =P.

Comment: Wow so I tried to write an answer but I still cannot for the life of me figure out how to parse this expression considering the position of those ampersands and parentheses. Can you help me out?

Comment: @StevenLu, The spiral rule (see my first comment) works fine for this. Start with the identifier, go right and hit a function taking a (start at the ampersand, go right to hit an array and then left to hit a type) reference to an array of N Ts, go left to hit the return type of a reference, go right to hit the array, and left to hit the type of the element.

Comment: @chris Hmm you're right. Yes that does work. However, I don't understand why if I take out the outer parens that I end up with a decl (which doesn't work) for an array of char references. I guess in that case `char &` becomes one "thing". This whole business of how to parse complicated types is a little beyond me, what with the special consequences of parens. I have made it this far using trial-and-error, and I reckon it will last me till the end, because by this point, I already know how to write a clang tool to spit out to me an AST parse of a type!

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I sort of figured out the answer. But not before Mr. @WhozCraig. Anyway:

The declaration here is a function declaration. There is no function implementation present. The reason that this does anything at all is because `sizeof` is a special little snowflake that is satisfied only knowing the type, and of course the function declaration gives `sizeof` what it needs.

As for what function we're actually declaring, this is getting much fuzzier, but supposedly its return type is reference to `char [N]` and I am sorry but I do not know what `T (&)[N]` means, I think this is a reference to `T [N]`... that's apparently the argument type of this function. Well, all that matters is that `sizeof` eventually somehow gets fed with a char[N] or a reference to such a type, which is enough for it to deduce the actual byte size of the buffer you gave to the original macro argument.

Looking at this some more, the bizarre syntax (which I can only assume is to indicate these are reference types) is to block out the possibility of pointer types going through here and ruining all of our byte-counting fun.

One question remains... I think this would really result in my `SIZEOF(buffer)` producing `5` which is actually **wrong**. Yes, 5 is the *size of* that buffer, but the *sizeof* called on the buffer is actually the real number of bytes it takes up. Therefore this has to be 20!

**Update:** I just went and tested this in Xcode. Yup. *Scandalous!*

```
int buffer[5];
std::cout << "omg" << SIZEOF(buffer) << std::endl;
```

output:

```
omg5
```

Great, now I have to make this work properly... Oh that wasn't too bad.

```
 namespace detail {
        template <typename T, size_t N>
-       char (&SIZEOF_ARRAY_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARG(T (&)[N]))[N];
+       char (&SIZEOF_ARRAY_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARG(T (&)[N]))[N * sizeof(T)];
 }
 #define SIZEOF(x) sizeof(detail::SIZEOF_ARRAY_REQUIRES_ARRAY_ARG(x))
```

output now:

```
omg20
```

Comment: It is for the very reason you showed here why MS called it `countof`. It certainly is not the size of the array. The odd looking syntax you see is the mechanism for declaring a function that returns reference to array of dim N. It isn't often used, but is standard supported. [See Vlad's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045860/1322972), as it briefly spells out the syntax.